# Change macro in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros

The macro 'propdp' creates a dependency property like this:

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

I would like to change it a bit.  To look like this:

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

Can this be done?  Does anyone know where to change this?

Answer (score 3):

Go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\NetFX30

There you will find propa.snippet and propdp.snippet.

Edit to do what you want...